# How do I style a div inside a component without passing props to that component (I'm using a package)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles

I'm using the [react-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollbar) package to render a scrollbar for my my content. What I also want is a arrow button that, on click, moves to a certain scrollbar area. **The problem is**, I'm trying to style (marginTop) a class inside my component. 
**This is my attempt:**

```
// MY COMPONENT

scrollToNextUpload = () => {
    const NextUpload = 400
    this.setState({ marginTop : this.state.marginTop + NextUpload }, () => document.getElementsByClassName('scrollarea-content')[0].style.marginTop = "'" + this.state.marginTop + "px'")
}

// MY RENDER
render () {
    <ScrollArea>
       // my content
       <div onClick={this.scrollToNext}></div>
    </ScrollArea>
}
```

**What is actually rendered**

```
<div class='scrollarea'>
   <div class='scrollarea-content'>
      // my content
      <div onClick={this.scrollToNext}></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

### What I want

To make my area with the scrollbar scroll,  I have to add a marginTop style to the 'scrollarea-content'. I could do this by passing props to the < ScrollArea > and then use them inside the installed package; but I'm trying to avoid altering the original package content.
Also, is there another way how I could scroll by click and is there someone else who's experienced with that NPM Package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most libraries give props to apply style to child components, in this library you can pass a className to the `contentClassName` or use inline style in `contentStyle` prop :

```
<ScrollArea contentStyle={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
```

An another way is to write css to add style to the `scrollarea-content` class.

In a `.css` file :

```
.scrollarea-content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Edit: In your case you can programatically change the `marginTop` style by using the props like this :

```
scrollToNextUpload = () => {
    const NextUpload = 400;
    this.setState(prevState => ({ marginTop : prevState.marginTop + NextUpload }));
}

render () {
    <ScrollArea contentStyle={{ marginTop: this.state.marginTop }}>
       // my content
       <div onClick={this.scrollToNext}></div>
    </ScrollArea>
}
```

Note the use of a functional `setState` to prevent inconsistencies when next state value depends on the previous state.

Comment: I completely read over the 'contentStyle' prop; thank you so much